# Closed form $\int_{a}^b \cfrac{1}{(1+x) \, \left[\ln(1-x)-\ln(1+x)\right]} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, closed-form

I am encountering an integral which involves logarithms, in particular,

\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^b \cfrac{1}{(1+x) \, \left[\ln(1-x)-\ln(1+x)\right]} \, \mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation}
where $a$ and $b$ are finite real numbers.

Does this integral have an closed form solution ? It seems that integration by parts does not work...

Comment: Perhaps you can expand as a Taylor series?

Comment: If you substitute $v=\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}$, I think it becomes $\int \frac{dv}{v(1+e^v)}$.  That doesn't look any easier, but it might be familiar to someone.

Comment: It's doubtful this has an antiderivative.  As @Michael points out, you can do some substitution to put it in simpler form, and then you can Taylor expand to obtain a series of exponential integrals.  Beyond that, pffft.

Answer (score 2):

As it has already been mentioned in the comment section, the simple substitution $t=\ln\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}$

leads to an integral of the form $\displaystyle\int\frac{dt}{t~(e^t+1)},~$ which does not possess a closed form expression

in terms of elementary functions and constants: see [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more details. However, its definite counterpart, when evaluated over the entire positive real

semiaxis, yields $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{t^n}{e^t+1}~=~n!~\eta(n+1)~$ for $n>-1,$ and $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{t^n}{e^t-1}=n!~\zeta(n+1)~$ for

$n>0:~$ see the [Riemann $\zeta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet $\eta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) functions for more information. Unfortunately, in our case $n=-1$, which means that the integral diverges, due to the fact that the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) has a pole at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

## Hint

> With $\ds{x = {1 - t \over 1 + t}}$:

\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b}{1 \over \pars{1 + x}\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - x} - \ln\pars{1 + x}}}
\,\dd x =
-\int_{\pars{1- a}/\pars{1 + a}}^{\pars{1 - b}/\pars{1 + b}}
{\dd t \over \pars{1 + t}\ln\pars{t}}
\end{align}

> A further procedure requires the *particular values* of $\ds{a}$ and $\ds{b}$. A useful expression is
>   $\ds{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}p^{q}\,\dd q\,\right\vert_{\ p\ \in\ \pars{0,1}} =
> -\,{1 \over \ln\pars{p}}}$.